# why is depth fail better than depth pass for shadow volumes?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx

I am having trouble understanding why depth fail is better. There is an issue with the eye of the camera being inside a shadow volume, I understand that part. So you need to cap front faces that were clipped by the near plane for depth pass to work. But for depth fail to work, you need to cap back faces.

Is it because capping for far plane is easier than capping for near plane? If so, why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The near-plane clipping problem is not fully solved by capping front faces; it will still fail in many situations when the camera is inside a shadow volume. This makes it unsuitable for roamable 3D environments with shadows.

Depth fail will work even without capping back faces; it will simply miss shadows where the volume points back to infinity. This is a MUCH less common situation than where depth pass occurs, which is any time the camera is in a shadow. Furthermore, there is hardware support to facilitate Z clamping:

OpenGL 3.2: [GL_DEPTH_CLAMP](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/depth_clamp.txt)

D3D10: [RasterizerDesc.DepthClipEnable = FALSE.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

However, for a robust solution, you usually need to put tweaks onto both; neither is used "in the raw". Depth pass is used for top down perspectives because the camera will never be in a shadow (and it's quite an effective technique in that field), where as depth fail is used in FPS's or other related games where being inside a shadow volume is a problem.

Here is a list of pro's and con's from a paper that is an [archetypal of the subject](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/the-theory-of-stencil-shadow-volumes-r1873):

**Depth-pass**

- Advantages

  - Does not require capping for shadow volumes
  - Less geometry to render
  - Faster of the two techniques
  - Easier to implement if we ignore the near plane clipping problem
  - Does not require an infinite perspective projection
- Disadvantages

  - Not robust due to unsolvable near plane clipping problem

**Depth-fail**

- Advantages

  - Robust solution since far plane clipping problem can be solved
    elegantly
- Disadvantages

  - Requires capping to form closed shadow volumes
  - More geometry to render due to capping
  - Slower of the two techniques
  - Slightly more difficult to implement
  - Requires an infinite perspective projection

Comment: It is worth pointing out that DX10/GL3 helps with the far-plane issue without requiring infinite projection by allowing clipping of only X and Y and ignoring Z. It is called *depth clamping* in GL3.2 ([GL_DEPTH_CLAMP](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/depth_clamp.txt)) and in D3D10 [`RasterizerDesc.DepthClipEnable = FALSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172408(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I probably should have followed the link before writing that comment... the extension is already discussed, though it is not obvious in that article that it is no longer an extension nor that it exists in D3D as well.

Comment: Why is near plane clipping not fully solved by capping front faces?

Comment: If the camera is in the shadow of a volume cast by an object behind it, there is no trivial way to cap it, and most of the ways to do this automatically (added bias, a pre-touch pass, etc) are slower than switching to depth fail. A good renderer will use depth pass usually, and switch to depth fail in certain circumstances, to get the power of both.